# Application.yml for config server not readable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configserver

I have a config server whose config file for client app looks like this .

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "Choosing Project..."

IP="10.90.21.244";
Port=9011;
Options="--spring.cloud.config.profiles.active=native -- 
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=/configurations/ -- 
spring.rabbitmq.host=$IP --spring.rabbitmq.host=5672 -- 
spring.rabbitmq.username=user --spring.rabbitmq.password=password"

mkdir -p configurations

cd configurations


cat <<EOF> application-research.yml

dataSources: (Here it is giving Exception)
  ccPlatform: 
    driver: some driver
    host: "some ip"
    name: ccPlatformDataSource
    password: "password"
```

Structure of `app.yml` is correct. Like space after colon .

But it throwing an error

> Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values
>   are  not allowed here  in 'reader', line 16, column 12:
>       dataSources: 
>                  ^

Answer (score 0):

Validate your yaml file content [here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and you can check about possible error.